# Comparing set components

Tags: python, function, set

I want to make a function which takes two sets A and B and returns True if A is less than B.

```
def set_less_than(A, B):
    Alist = list(A)
    Blist = list(B)

    ans = []

    for index in range(len(A)):
        try:
            ans.append(Alist[index] < Blist[index])
        except TypeError:
            ans.append("impossible to compare")

    return ans
```

However, how can I handle this case, 
for example:

> A = { 0, 'b', (0, 'a') } and B = { 1, 'a', (2, -3) }

I want a output like

> [True, False, (True, 'impossible')]

Comment: You realize sets don't have any particular order, right?

Comment: First, sets don't have any order - so it's impossible to pick up certain elements by index or assure that after transforming to list you'd have certain elements on certain indexes. Second, thing you've written in description of the problem is not quite true - unless according to the example that you've given (You don't want to compare sets - but sets elements).

Comment: What does less than mean in this context?

Comment: I know that sets have no order. All I want to do is just comparing the value of the elements shown in the example.

Comment: less means literally less. Here's some example. { 0.5, 1.5, 2.5 } is less than { 1, 2, 3 } / and /
{ 'a', 'b' } is less than { 'ab', 'bb' }

Comment: We assume that the given set is already ordering set.

Comment: You should've just asked this with something that's actually ordered, like a list or a tuple, instead of set. You even already wrote your desired output as a list.

Comment: "less means literally less."  The word "literally" does not mean "Whatever is in my mind, because what I think a word means should be completely obvious to everyone else without any explanation". The only remotely canonical ordering of sets is the subset order. This isn't the Psychic SE. If you can't explicitly articulate what you want done, then of course you're not going to be able to code it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tough question to answer because, as [Scott points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47037554/comparing-set-components#comment81021648_47037554), the answer will be nonsensical, as sets are unordered.  That is: the items cannot be compared in order.  So attempting to grab each item, in order, by index, subsequently won't work.  Furthermore, it does not make sense to say that an alphabetic character is *less than* another one.  Same thing applies to tuples.

But if this is indeed *really* want you want to do, this is how I'd do it:

1. See if the items are integers ().
2. If so, compare them and append the `True` or `False` value.
3. If not, append `"impossible"`.

```
def set_less_than(set_a, set_b):
    list_a = list(set_a)
    list_b = list(set_b)

    ans = []

    for index in range(len(list_a)):

        if isinstance(list_a[index], int) and isinstance(list_b[index], int):
            ans.append(list_a[index] < list_b[index])
        else:
            ans.append("impossible")

    return ans

a = set([0, 'b', (0, 'a')])
b = set([1, 'a', (2, -3)])

answer = set_less_than(a, b)

for a in answer:
    print a
```

In my case, `0` is compared to `'a'`, etc.  Every item compared returns 
`"impossible"`.

Comment: Although it should be pointed out that strings **can** be evaluated in that way in Python: `'a' < 'b'` or `'A' < 'a'` -- which may not yield the answer one expects it to (both of these statements evaluates to True). That is not to say that they *should* be compared this way.

Comment: @DaveL17 Noted, I'm assuming this actually compares the ASCII values of the characters or something - but the OP didn't clarify what they meant when they said they want to see if one is "less than" the other.  "Should `'a' > 'A'`?" would be a good follow-up question.

Comment: Oh yes, just suggesting that it is logically *possible* to compare string values (from the docs: `Strings are compared lexicographically using the numeric equivalents (the result of the built-in function ord()) of their characters. Unicode and 8-bit strings are fully interoperable in this behavior.)` I wasn't pointing to a shortcoming of your post.

Comment: @DaveL17 *"You are technically correct - the best kind of correct"* :)